# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Java using hash code

Tags: java, hash, dijkstra

The implementation for my graph is the following hash table:

```
public class DiGraphHash{

private int numNodos, numArcos;
private TheList<Nodo> nodos[];
private TheList<Arco> arcos[];
private TheList<Arco> preds[];
```

}

where TheList, is a list I made myself.

For Dijkstra's algorithm I need to map The cost of each node and the path to reach that node. 
I have the following two arrays:

```
   int[] cost = new cost[num_nodes];
   Nodo[] path = new Nodo[num_nodes];
```

Another important detail, is that my nodes are going to be the letters A, B, C, D.

So when I map my nodes, for example lets say I have to assign the cost the the Node A, how do I find the position in the array?

I was thinking of using hashcode % array.length but I am not sure if I will get collisions (take into consideration that it will be only 1 char letters)

I am not asking about the code, and need the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Add a `cost` field to your `Nodo` class.  This way, you'll only have to manage an array of nodes, rather than a separate array of costs as well.  You can assign the costs when you instantiate the nodes, and look them up easily later.
2. A better data structure than two arrays might be a map, where the keys are the nodes themselves and the values are the nodes' costs.  Here's an example:

> ```
> HashMap<Nodo, Integer> nodesToCosts = new HashMap<Nodo, Integer>();
>
> nodes.put(nodeA, new Integer(5));
> nodes.put(nodeB, new Integer(20));
> nodes.put(nodeC, new Integer(10));
> nodes.put(nodeD, new Integer(5));
> ```

Comment: ok I like the idea! thanks. 
and how about this: to save the shortest "path" to each node I am going to make an array of List, where the List has Arco (Arcs in English) and this way I can use Hashcode to find the Arc of a node, and the source of that Arc is going to be the "shortest predecesor. dont know if i explained myself well.

Comment: That sounds promising.  You might also check out Java implementations from others: http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29